# How to put YAD form fields value into variable after submit?

Tags: 18.04, bash, scripts, zenity, yad

How to put YAD form fields value into variable after submit?

My script actually looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

default_jpg='/';
default_mp3='/';
default_resolution='1920:1080';
default_filename="/";

OUTPUT=$(yad \
  --title="JPG and MP3 to MP4" \
  --form \
    --text="Options" \
    --separator="," \
    --field="JPG:FL" \
    --field="MP3:FL" \
    --field="Resolution" \
    --field="MP4 (Output):SFL" \
    --button="Create MP4":1 \
    "$default_jpg" \
    "$default_mp3" \
    "$default_resolution" \
    "$default_filename" \
  ) accepted=$?

if ((accepted == 1)); then
  jpgfile=$(   awk -F, '{print $1}' <<<$OUTPUT)
  mp3file=$(   awk -F, '{print $2}' <<<$OUTPUT)
  resolution=$(awk -F, '{print $3}' <<<$OUTPUT)
  filename=$(  awk -F, '{print $4}' <<<$OUTPUT)

  echo $jpgfile $mp3file $resolution $filename
fi
```

I fail to put the values of the form fields into variable. If this would work instead of just echoing the variables I would like to use them in this command:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i "$jpgfile" -i "$mp3file" -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest -vf scale=$resolution "$filename"
```

Please tell me what is wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [this post](https://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Blogs/Productivity-Sauce/Dress-Up-Bash-Scripts-with-YAD), to parse the parameters of a form from YAD in the bash/shell on Linux you can:

```
VAR=$(echo $YAD_OUTPUT | awk 'BEGIN {FS="," } { print $1 }')
```

Where:

- `VAR` is the name of the variable where you want to store the value of the YAD entry.
- `$YAD_OUTPUT` is self-explanatory. In your case, you named that variable "`OUTPUT`"
- `FS=","` is the separator value. In your case, "`,`".
- `$1` is the position of the first `--field`. In your case, the content of `$default_jpg` (`/`).

Here is the corrected example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

default_jpg='/';
default_mp3='/';
default_resolution='1920:1080';
default_filename="/";

OUTPUT=$(yad \
  --title="JPG and MP3 to MP4" \
  --form \
    --text="Options" \
    --separator="," \
    --field="JPG:FL" \
    --field="MP3:FL" \
    --field="Resolution" \
    --field="MP4 (Output):SFL" \
    --button="Create MP4":1 \
    "$default_jpg" \
    "$default_mp3" \
    "$default_resolution" \
    "$default_filename" \
) accepted=$?

if ((accepted == 1)); then
  jpgfile=$(echo $OUTPUT | awk 'BEGIN {FS="," } { print $1 }')
  mp3file=$(echo $OUTPUT | awk 'BEGIN {FS="," } { print $2 }')
  resolution=$(echo $OUTPUT | awk 'BEGIN {FS="," } { print $3 }')
  filename=$(echo $OUTPUT | awk 'BEGIN {FS="," } { print $4 }')

  echo $jpgfile $mp3file $resolution $filename
fi
```

> The start of this answer is to help Google to find this solution.